# Convert one element tuple (int) to str

Tags: python, string, tuples

Assuming a tuple with one integer:

```
tup = (19201,)
```

I am looking for a way to get this output:

```
tup = "(19201)"
```

So far I have tried this:

```
str_tup = "(" + tup[0] + ")"
```

But it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way than concatenation is to use Python’s formatting syntax:

```
str_tup = '({})'.format(tup[0])
```

[`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) will replace the `{}` with the argument you give it (here: your tuple value).

Better yet, you can generalise this to tuples of higher arity:

```
str_tup = '({})'.format(', '.join([str(x) for x in tup]))
```

This uses Python’s [list comprehension syntax](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3) to convert all tuple elements to strings, and then uses `join` to concatenate them using a joining string.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
str(tup).replace(',', '')
```

or

```
"(" + str(tup[0]) + ")"
```

You must convert explicitly the int into a str